# Brocken metadata class generation via protobuf on alpine Docker images

Tags: php, docker, protocol-buffers, alpine-linux

Sometime ago I've used ubuntu image for PHP files generation via protoc lib and it generates some metadata classes with normal hashes used by protobuf.
It was generated smth like:

```php
namespace MyApp\ProtobufMetadata\Schema\v1;

class Request
{
    public static $is_initialized = false;

    public static function initOnce() {
        $pool = \Google\Protobuf\Internal\DescriptorPool::getGeneratedPool();

        if (static::$is_initialized == true) {
          return;
        }
        $pool->internalAddGeneratedFile(hex2bin(
            "0acd010a236170692f636174616c6f672f736368656d612f76312f726571756573742e70726f746f121d6170692e636174616c6f672e736368656d612e76312e72657175657374221d0a0a47657452657175657374120f0a0776657273696f6e18012001280d4260ca022d4350515c5368617265645c53657276696365735c436174616c6f675c536368656d615c76315c52657175657374e2022d4350515c5368617265645c50726f746f6275664d657461646174615c436174616c6f675c536368656d615c7631620670726f746f33"
        ), true);

        static::$is_initialized = true;
    }
}
```

But now I need to use alpine usage.
I've created Dockerfile with installing protobuf from github:

```yaml
ENV PROTOBUF_VERSION 3.19.4
ENV PROTOBUF_URL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v"$PROTOBUF_VERSION"/protobuf-cpp-"$PROTOBUF_VERSION".zip
RUN curl -L -o protobuf.zip "$PROTOBUF_URL"
RUN unzip protobuf.zip && cd protobuf-"$PROTOBUF_VERSION" && ./configure && make -j$(nproc) && make install

RUN cd .. && rm protobuf.zip
```

But after this when I generates new classes it generates metadata classes in some strange view:

```php
<?php
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: api/schema/v1/request.proto

namespace MyApp\ProtobufMetadata\Schema\v1;

class Request
{
    public static $is_initialized = false;

    public static function initOnce() {
        $pool = \Google\Protobuf\Internal\DescriptorPool::getGeneratedPool();

        if (static::$is_initialized == true) {
          return;
        }
        $pool->internalAddGeneratedFile(
            '
�
#api/schema/v1/request.protoapi.schema.v1.request"

GetRequest
version (
B`�-MyApp\\Services\\Catalog\\Schema\\v1\\Request�-MyApp\\ProtobufMetadata\\Catalog\\Schema\\v1bproto3'
        , true);

        static::$is_initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Does anyone hit with similar problem?
Is any way to fix lib installation or some compile to return pretty code with hex2bin usage?

compilation was made via commands with RoadRunner usage:

```
[ -f ./protoc-gen-php-grpc ] || ./rr get-protoc-binary
      && chmod +x ./protoc-gen-php-grpc
      && ./rr compile-proto-files"
```

Host system is MacOS

Answer (score 0):

This was done on purpose, your Alpine is probably just running a more recent version of protoc.

Here is the PR which removed the hex2bin call: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/8006

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).